# EXCEL - COUNT OF Cells in column A where value is NOT Numeric BUT where Column B = "X"

Tags: excel

Data

I have 2 columns in a table - 'AppRef' and 'HoursLost'..
AppRef contains single alpha characters (A,B,C etc)
HoursLost contains a combination of blank entries, numeric and alphanumeric values ('','ABC123',123 etc)

Im trying to obtain a Count of the number of records where HoursLost **IS NOT** Numeric BUT also where APPRef = "C".

Ive been struggling with COUNTIFS and SUMPRODUCT functions for some time so thought id reach out for help..

Do you know how I bring together the 2 functions to achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try `=SUMPRODUCT(--NOT(ISNUMBER(Table1[HoursLost])),--(Table1[AppRef]="C"))`, substituting the name of your table for `Table1`.

If you want to count values of `AppRef` containing "C" rather than identical to "C", you can change the second condition to `--NOT(ISERROR(FIND("C",Table1[AppRef])))`.

Comment: Doesnt that give me a Sim of the HourLost for records with a value of C in the AppRef..??

What im needing is a count of records where AppRef=C and HoursLost IS NOT NUMERIC

Comment: My bad. Edited the answer to negate the result of `ISNUMBER()` using `NOT()`. It doesn't give you a sum of those values though, just a count of rows for which both conditions are true (which is part of the reason for using `--`).

Comment: OK thats great thankyou

Dont suppose you know if you can apply Wildcard to the condition Table1[AppRef]="C" do you?

So rather than ="C" - to include contains "C"

Comment: You can indeed - see edit (and you may also want to edit your question to include that requirement).

Answer (score 0):

I have put "AppRef" in column "A" and "Hourslost" in "B".

I have created a helper column "C" with following formula:

```
=AND(A2="C",NOT(ISNUMBER(B2))) // for cell C2
=AND(A3="C",NOT(ISNUMBER(B3))) // for cell C3
...
```

At the end, I've entered following formula:

```
=COUNTIF(C2:C10,TRUE)
```